# Unit testing code with PromiseKit usage

Tags: ios, unit-testing, asynchronous, promisekit, xctestexpectation

I'm trying to test `Diary` class that has dependency to `Network`.

So `Diary` code:

```
- (PMKPromise *)saveAndUploadToServer:(DiaryItem *)item
{
    return [self save:item].then(^{
        return [self upload:item]; << See UPDATE //I put breakpoint here, it is never called
    });
}

- (PMKPromise *)save:(DiaryItem *)item
{
    return [PMKPromise new:^(PMKPromiseFulfiller fulfill, PMKPromiseRejecter reject) {
        [self.entryCreationManagedContext performBlock:^{
            BOOL success;
            NSError *saveError = nil;

            item.status = @(UploadingStatus);
            success = [self.entryCreationManagedContext save:&saveError];

            if (success) {
                fulfill(item.objectID);
            }
            else {
                reject(saveError);
            }
        }];
    }];
}

- (PMKPromise*)upload:(DiaryItem*)item
{
    return [self.network POST:self.diaryUrl parameters:[item dictionary]].then(^{
         return [self reportUploadAnalytics];
    });
}
```

And the test:

```
- (void)testFailedUploadingReportsAnalytics
{
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Operations completed"];

    [self uploadToServerAndReturnCallback].finally(^{
        [expectation fulfill];
    });

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        assertThat(error, is(nilValue()));

        //check that mock called
    }];
}
```

The `Network` is mock in this test. But what I see that chain of promises is not executed. It stuck. Maybe because `then:` block is called on main thread as well `XCTest` is pausing it. But at the same time it should probably continue after 5 sec. What can be the issue?

**UPDATE**

Looks like it is nothing with my original assumption. If I replace `[self.entryCreationManagedContext save:&saveError]` with `YES` then debug reaches breakpoint.

**UPDATE 2**

It looks like issue with this particular saving of managed context. It is triggering notification about synchronising another managed contexts. And we are discovering what else there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ended up in different issue and nothing connected to PromiseKit.

We discovered growing amount of used memory. That `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` was producing deadlock on different store coordinators. After fixing that tests started working as expected.